# Propagate the error in sagemaker from ProcessingStep to Worflow functions

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

So I have a sagemaker worflow composed of multiple processing steps, training steps ...

I'm trying to change the `FailureReason` of the `describe_pipeline_execution()` to return useful information concerning the failure of my Sagemaker pipeline.

Indeed in my processing step and in my training step, having their code inside a docker container,  I want the pipeline to fail for various reasons. In the documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/build-your-own-processing-container.html) for processing step and [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/your-algorithms-training-algo-output.html) for training step, it is possible to return something by writing it in a file during the step through the functions `DescribeProcessingJob` or `DescribeTrainingJob`.

I was wondering if there is a path like `/opt/ml/failure` to put the output of my process so the function `describe_pipeline_execution()` can return what I want. Can't find it in the documentation!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this. You can log outputs from your scripts and view the logs in CloudWatch to help understand the error. You can also write to a file inside the job and upload it to S3 through a ProcessingOuput in the case of Processing jobs or by specifying the S3 path inside your training script. There's no reserved location for the errors but nothing stops you from writing your error logs and uploading them to S3.

I work at AWS and my opinions are my own.